# How to fail a nightwatch.js test within an if failure

Tags: javascript, if-statement, nightwatch.js

I have an **if** statement that, when it 'fails', I'd like it to fail my nightwatch test.

So at the moment an excerpt of my code looks like this;

```
   if (rangeFacetEntry.value.length === rangePageElement.length) {
     if (JSON.stringify(rangeArray) === JSON.stringify(rangePageElement)) {
       console.log("Range - they are the same");
         return true;
           } else {
               console.log("Range - they are not the same");
                 return false;
             }
           }
     });
```

But when it fails (i.e. JSON.stringify(rangeArray) does **not** equal JSON.stringify(rangePageElement)) then I would like it to **fail** my test.

But it doesn't.

It simply doesn't output the result to the terminal, and the overall test passes.

Is there a way I can make this failure within my **if** statement implicitly fail my test? Thanks.

Comment: have to tried creating a custom command as described in the documentation here

https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch-docs/blob/master/guide/extending-nightwatch/custom-commands.md

Nightwatch uses flags to mark test cases as pass/fail and using custom command should solve the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

With any JS test framework the “norm” is to throw an error.

```
function throwIfNotEqual( a, b ) {
    if( a !== b ) {
        throw new Error( 'a !== b' );
    }

    return true;
}

if( throwIfNotEqual( 'a1', 'a1' ) ) {
    console.log( 'we are here now' );
}

if( throwIfNotEqual( 'b1', 'b2' ) ) {
    console.log( 'this will not be called because the error is thrown' );
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply @iSkore, but this doesn't seem to have sorted the issue in my nightwatch test script, as it's still not 'failing'. I presumed that;   `console.log("Range - they are the same");
         return true;
           } else {
               console.log("Range - they are not the same");
                 // the nightwatch test fails now;
             }
           }
     });` would be quite straightforward, but it seems to be anything but. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.